# Type is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given

```
export type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

type AddDoSomething<T> = Omit<T, 'doSomething'> & {
  doSomething: () => void
}

class A<T> {
  public type: T
}

class B<TT> extends A<AddDoSomething<TT>> { }

// Just to check type match
type Test<T extends typeof A> = unknown

type C = Test<typeof B> // Error -> Type 'typeof B' does not satisfy the constraint 'typeof A'. Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
```

Why is that? I was trying to add a property to some type, and by omitting first, i want to make sure that there is no overlap type to 'doSomething'

*EDIT -------*

**BUT**
If i change the type of

> AddDoSomething

to

```
type AddDoSomething<T> = T & {
  doSomething: () => void
}
```

Then everything is alright, any insight? Is there any way i could overwrite the method of 'doSomething' without omitting it?

[Link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AddDoSomething%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Omit%3CT%2C%20%22doSomething%22%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%09doSomething%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20type%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%3CTT%3E%20extends%20A%3CAddDoSomething%3CTT%3E%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Test%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20A%3E%20%3D%20unknown%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20C%20%3D%20Test%3Ctypeof%20B%3E%0D%0A)

Comment: theres no implementation of `doSomething` in `B`

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean by that? Also see my editted question

Comment: Is there a reason you're not setting the value of `type` in the constructor of `A`?  Under `--strict` compiler options this is an issue... if I do `const a = new A<{foo: string}>()`, and I access `a.type.foo.charAt(0)` it will blow up at runtime.  It doesn't *really* matter for the answer to this question, but it makes the argument for why one breaks and the other succeeds harder to frame.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, long story short i was hacking my way to get the generic T type provided for base class A, in my code it was written with __DO_NOT_USE_TYPE_REFERENCE_ONLY_type so that later i could get the generic of A (the T) by calling A['__DO_NOT_USE_TYPE_REFERENCE_ONLY_type'] --> mainly for Intellisense purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense that `typeof B` does not extend `typeof A`, at least in the static type system.  It is quite possible that the two types behave identically at runtime, especially since you aren't actually *setting* the `type` property anywhere... but such an "okay at runtime despite looking bad in the type system" behavior is hard for the compiler to reason about.  You might need to use a type assertion if you know more than it does.

Let's walk through why the error makes sense:

```
export type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

type AddDoSomething<T> = Omit<T, "doSomething"> & {
    doSomething: () => void
}

class A<T> {
    public type!: T // forget about setting this
}

class B<T> extends A<AddDoSomething<T>> { }
```

So you have explicitly made `B<T>` equivalent to `A<AddDoSomething<T>>`.  But this means that `B<T>` is *not* equivalent to `A<T>`, precisely because some values of `T` might have a `doSomething` property that isn't a no-arg function.  And if the constructor `B` makes `B` instances, and the constructor `A` makes `A` instances, then you can't say that the `B` constructor extends the `A` constructor.  Your `Test` check failure is the same as this failure:

```
// if typeof B extends typeof A, then I can do this:
const NotReallyA: typeof A = B; // error!
// that error is the same as your Test.  Why did it happen?
```

If that were to compile just fine, then the compiler would think that `NotReallyA` was an `A` constructor, when it's really a `B` constructor.  But:

```
const legitimateA = new A<{ x: number, doSomething: number }>();
legitimateA.type.x = 1; // okay, x is number
legitimateA.type.doSomething = 2; // okay, doSomething is number

const legitimateB = new B<{ x: number, doSomething: number }>();
legitimateB.type.x = 1; // okay, x is number
legitimateB.type.doSomething = 2; // error! doSomething is ()=>void
legitimateB.type.doSomething = () => console.log("ok"); // okay now
```

You can see that legitimateA and legitimateB act differently... so you'd get different and incompatible behavior if you use `B` in place of `A` (via `NotReallyA`):

```
const illegitimateA = new NotReallyA<{ x: number, doSomething: number }>();
illegitimateA.type.x = 1; // okay, x is number
illegitimateA.type.doSomething = 2; // okay at compiler time, but not good
```

Now, since you're not setting `type`, in fact the two constructors are essentially the same at runtime.  If you really want the compiler to treat `B` like an `A` constructor, you can do it:

```
// Are you sure this is okay?  Then:
const OkayIGuessA = B as typeof A; // assertion
```

But it's not possible just to tell the compiler not to worry about the *types* `typeof B` and `typeof A` being incompatible.

---

If you are willing to prevent `T` from having its own `doSomething` property, or at least not one with a different type, then you can give up on `Omit` and use your other method of intersection.  This produces a valid subtype of `T` and everything is fine... a `T & {doSomething(): void}` can be used everywhere a `T` can.  If `T` happens to have a `doSomething` property, the intersection makes a useless `never` type, so we should probably prohibit that:

```
// Give up on Omit
class DifferentB<T extends {
    doSomething?: () => void;
    [k: string]: unknown;
}> extends A<T & { doSomething: () => void }> { }
```

And we can use it:

```
const diffB = new DifferentB<{ x: number }>();
diffB.type.x = 1; // okay
diffB.type.doSomething = () => console.log("okay"); // okay
```

And we don't have to worry about naughty incompatible `doSomething` properties:

```
const forbiddenB = new DifferentB<{ x: number, doSomething: number }>(); // error!
// number is not ()=>void
```

And we can reassign the constructor because `typeof DifferentB` *does* extend `typeof A`:

```
const DemonstrablyOkayA: typeof A = DifferentB; // also okay
```

Okay, hope that helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AddDoSomething%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Omit%3CT%2C%20%22doSomething%22%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%09doSomething%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20type!%3A%20T%20%2F%2F%20forget%20about%20setting%20this%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%3CTT%3E%20extends%20A%3CAddDoSomething%3CTT%3E%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20if%20typeof%20B%20extends%20typeof%20A%2C%20then%20I%20can%20do%20this%3A%0D%0Aconst%20NotReallyA%3A%20typeof%20A%20%3D%20B%3B%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%2F%2F%20that%20error%20is%20the%20same%20as%20your%20Test.%20%20Why%20did%20it%20happen%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20A%20~%20new%3CT%3E()%20%3D%3E%20%7Btype%3A%20T%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20B%20~%20new%3CT%3E()%20%3D%3E%20%7Btype%3A%20Omit%3CT%2C%20%22doSomething%22%3E%20%26%20%7BdoSomething%3A()%3D%3Evoid%7D%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20legitimateA%20%3D%20new%20A%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%2C%20doSomething%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0AlegitimateA.type.x%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%2C%20x%20is%20number%0D%0AlegitimateA.type.doSomething%20%3D%202%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%2C%20doSomething%20is%20number%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20legitimateB%20%3D%20new%20B%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%2C%20doSomething%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0AlegitimateB.type.x%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%2C%20x%20is%20number%0D%0AlegitimateB.type.doSomething%20%3D%202%3B%20%2F%2F%20error!%20doSomething%20is%20()%3D%3Evoid%0D%0AlegitimateB.type.doSomething%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(%22ok%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%20now%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20You%20can%20see%20that%20legitimateA%20and%20legitimateB%20act%20differently%0D%0A%2F%2F%20so%20you%20can't%20just%20pretend%20that%20the%20B%20constructor%20is%20an%20A%20constructor%3A%0D%0Aconst%20illegitimateA%20%3D%20new%20NotReallyA%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%2C%20doSomething%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0AillegitimateA.type.x%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%2C%20x%20is%20number%0D%0AillegitimateA.type.doSomething%20%3D%202%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%20at%20compiler%20time%2C%20but%20not%20good%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Are%20you%20sure%20this%20is%20okay%3F%20%20Then%3A%0D%0Aconst%20OkayIGuessA%20%3D%20B%20as%20typeof%20A%3B%20%2F%2F%20assertion%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Give%20up%20on%20Omit%0D%0Aclass%20DifferentB%3CT%20extends%20%7B%0D%0A%09doSomething%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%09%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20unknown%3B%0D%0A%7D%3E%20extends%20A%3CT%20%26%20%7B%20doSomething%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%20%7D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20diffB%20%3D%20new%20DifferentB%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0AdiffB.type.x%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0AdiffB.type.doSomething%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(%22okay%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20forbiddenB%20%3D%20new%20DifferentB%3C%7B%20x%3A%20number%2C%20doSomething%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%3B%20%2F%2F%20error!%0D%0A%2F%2F%20number%20is%20not%20()%3D%3Evoid%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20DemonstrablyOkayA%3A%20typeof%20A%20%3D%20DifferentB%3B%20%2F%2F%20also%20okay%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your time explaining this to me. It is very clear now.